# Nth root of complex number (z)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to prove that:

> Prove that $\displaystyle z^{\frac{1}{n}}=e ^{\frac{1}{n}(\text{Log }z+2k\pi i)}$ gives the $n$th root of $z$, taking $k=0,1,2, \ldots$

Well, with the suggestion of Gerry and the help of wolfram, i have this

$$z^{\frac{1}{n}}=z \cdot e ^{2k\pi i}$$

$$z^{\frac{1}{n}}=z \cdot \left(\frac{\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)}{n}\right)$$

But I think, i should get this

$$z^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(\frac{\cos(2k\pi)}{n}+\frac{i\sin(2k\pi)}{n}\right)$$

Any suggestion?

Comment: Start by raising the right side to the power $n$, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written
$$z^{\frac{1}{n}}=z \cdot e ^{2k\pi i}$$

which isn't quite right;
taking $n$th powers should give you
$$
z = e^{2k \pi i + \text{Log } z} = z e^{2k \pi i}
$$
instead.  So then you get
$$
z = z\left( \cos 2 k \pi i + i \sin 2 k \pi i \right)
$$
or
$$
z = z (1 + i)0
$$
$$
z = z
$$

Which is true.
So, working backwards, what we've basically shown is that
$$
\left(e^{2 k \pi i + \text{Log } z} \right)^n = z
$$
for any $k$.
I don't know what your definition of an "$n$th root" of $z$ is, but my definition of an $n$th root of $z$ is a number $a$ such that $a^n = z$.
So the above shows that
$e^{2 k \pi i + \text{Log } z}$ is an $n$th root of $z$.